# Log scale axis ticks & labels not removed after setting custom linear ticks

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm plotting with `matplotlib`. When I set the x-scale to `'log'` and change the tick labels and formatting to display linearly, the logspace tick labels don't go away, and I end up with two sets of xticklabels (one linear and one logspace).

This didn't happen on another machine, so I think it is version-specific? Right now I'm working in Jupyter Notebook with matplotlib 2.0.2 and python 3.6.1.

MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
%matplotlib inline
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
xmin = 5
xmax = 50
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xticklabels(np.logspace(np.log10(xmin), np.log10(xmax), num=6))
ax.set_xticks(np.logspace(np.log10(xmin), np.log10(xmax), num=6))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.0f'))
ax.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
```

[image]

Comment: Not quite a MWE. What is `x`, `y1`, and `y2`?

Comment: oops, sorry, didn't think the details of what I was plotting were relevant. edited my post to include more of the code.

Comment: It's not the names that matter. The idea of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is that I should be able to run the code on my machine. Currently I have no idea what values are in `distance` etc. It would be helpful if you could create some fake data that reproduces the problem and remove everything that is not relevent e.g the `fill_between`

Comment: oh I see, hope these last edits are useable.

Comment: Yep. Now thats a MWE :)